# Nebula Awards needs WorldBuilder help

Tags: discussion

Each year, the Nebula Award organizers host "office hours" where experts in various fields are available for authors to talk about problems in their books. This year, because COVID, the office hours will be online. They are asking for experts in any self-declared field to volunteer 1 hour of time for 4 fifteen-minute interviews from writers. Details [here](https://nebulas.sfwa.org/experts-needed/). If you want to volunteer, send an e-mail with your name and field(s) of expertise to Anne Tibbets at OfficeHours@sfwa.org

Comment: I'm not sure one can be an expert in worldbuilding. A lot of worldbuilding is just making something believable out of the unreal or implausible.

Comment: @frostfyre True. But that’s not what is being asked for here. Really, these folks are just asking extended Worldbuilding questions in various domains, and without being closed for being plot oriented. :-) Think of it as live-action Worldbuilding... just declare what your area of world expertise is: astrophysics, military strategy, font design... lots of us answer questions in specific domains easier than others. 

And I’m now disappointed that font design has never been critical to anyone’s world enough to ask about it here. I could probably nail that question! :-)

Comment: I want to see that font design question.